# Downloading a text file in ASP.NET is appending the web page HTML

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, download

Thanks to help I previously received [on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426219/how-do-i-send-a-binary-blob-to-a-client-browser) I was able to get my asp.net web site to download all kinds of files to the client browser.

For some odd reason, when I download text files, the HTML of the web page is being appended to the text!  All other file types work fine!

Here's the code that's doing the download:

```
  Public Sub DownloadBlob(ByVal Blob As Byte(), ByVal FileName As String, ByVal Response As HttpResponse)
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", FileName.Replace(" ", "_")))
    Response.ContentType = String.Format("application/{0}", Path.GetExtension(FileName).Substring(1))
    Response.BinaryWrite(Blob)
  End Sub
```

and here's what's coming out of my text file:

```
Here is a test file
I hope it works!
:)
Saul

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    EEI - Case
</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="EEI.css" />

  <script language="javascript" id="jssembleWare" src="sembleWare.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="EEICaseEditForm.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<!--Script to confirm btnEditDocument Action-->
```

I didn't include everything; you get the idea.

So, what is wrong with my code, and how do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call `Response.End`.

```
Public Sub DownloadBlob(ByVal Blob As Byte(), ByVal FileName As String, ByVal Response As HttpResponse)
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", FileName.Replace(" ", "_")))
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.BinaryWrite(Blob)
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Also notice I set the ContentType a little differently.